# Use JQuery to select div having specific inline style

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a html page generated from a backend, so that I cannot edit anything in this page.

The page doesn't have any id or class name, but it has inline style inside `<div>`.

I use Jquery to select DIVs which have `style="width: 50%;"` and apply a red color to its text.

I have tried couple ways, but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

```js
$(function(){
    if ( $('div').css('width') == '50%;') {
        $('div').css('color', 'red')
    }
     /*  if($('div').is('[style="width: 50%;"]')) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red')
      } */
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 50%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div style="width: 90%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div style="width: 50%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div style="position: relative;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Attribute-Contains Selector for style:

```
 $(function () {
        $('div[style*="width: 50%"]').css("color", "red");
 });
```

Jquery Reference:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Attribute-Contains Selector:

```js
 $(function () {
        $('div[style*="width: 50%"]').css("color", "red");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 50%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div style="width: 90%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div style="width: 50%;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div style="position: relative;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```